# In Dropdown Laravel Blade show option in optgroup based upon a field in the table

Tags: php, laravel, dropdown, optgroup

I have a table which screenshot is attached below
[image: database image]

I  want to show all the Account Type and but it should be  shown in option group

[image: select image]

How can I achieve this???

[image: dropdown image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Laravel helper function groupBy() will help you solve this problem.
Data grouping example:

```
$cars = Car::where('status', 1)->get();
    
$carModels = $cars->groupBy('model');
```

Blade example:

```
<select name="car_id">
    @foreach($carModels as $model => $cars)
    
      <optgroup label="{{ $model }}">
        @foreach($cars as $car)
          <option value="{{ $car->id }}">{{ $car->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </optgroup>
    
    @endforeach
</select>
```